# CAS SSO with Java EE Web Container Authentication

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security, single-sign-on, cas

I'm new to Spring 3.1 and I've been using Java EE Web Container Authentication so far for security (the `<jee>` tag has come in quite handy). However, the project that I'm working on has a few separate applications that need to have access to the current user's information without logging in multiple times.

Not wanting to reinvent the wheel, I've struggled with using CAS over the past couple of days and have finally got it working with the example that comes with the package. Now, what I would like to do is use the web container setup that I've created in an individual system and use it in CAS. Is this possible or do I need to be looking into some other form of gathering the user's roles?

Comment: 1) What Servlet Container do you use? JBoss or Tomcat?
2) Do you have all application on the same container?

Comment: 1. Developing it on a local tomcat server and deploying it to a hierarchy (dev, qa, prod) of WebSphere Application Servers. 2. Running on different VMs on the same server for now but they may be placed on separate servers in the future.

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Since you use Java EE authentication your SSO framework should support Java EE agent.
In your case SSO framework should support WebSphere. 
Unfortunately, open source providers like CAS and JOSSO (http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/Setup+JOSSO+Agent+%28SP%29) do not support WebSphere.
Probably you need to use commercial SSO framework, lice SiteMinder:
https://supportcontent.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20SiteMinder%20Agent%20for%20WebSphere%20r12%20SP2-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/HTML/index.htm?toc.htm?941171.html

Alternative approach is to abandon Java EE authentication and use SpringSecurity authentication in all your applications. In this case you will be able to use CAS or JOSSO.

Comment: I apologize for the late response. I would love to abandon Java EE authentication, as it has been nothing but a pain in my side to get working. Unfortunately, the only way that I know of to get security information out of an Active Directory directly from WebSphere is to use the container authentication. I haven't looked into a way around using WebSphere directly (like using LDAP) because I feared it being a laborious task but maybe that's my only option here?